# How extract several imputed values from several variables using mice or another package in R into a single dataset?

Tags: r, dataset, imputation, r-mice, hmisc

From the multiple imputation output (e.g., object of class mids for mice) I want to extract several imputed values for some of the imputed variables into a single dataset that also includes original data with the missing values.

Here are sample dataset and code:

```
library("mice")
nhanes
tempData <- mice(nhanes, seed = 23109)
```

Using the code below I can extract these values for each variable into separate datasets:

```
age_imputed<-as.data.frame(tempData$imp$age) 
bmi_imputed<-as.data.frame(tempData$imp$bmi) 
hyp_imputed<-as.data.frame(tempData$imp$hyp) 
chl_imputed<-as.data.frame(tempData$imp$chl)
```

But I want to extract several variables to preserve the order of the rows for further analysis.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `complete` function from `mice` package to extract the complete data set including the imputations:

```
complete(tempData, action = 1)
```

`action` argument takes the imputation number or if you need it in "all", "long" formats etc. Refer *R documentation*.